# Why aren't media files autogenerated in Django?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

So i create same project which accepts input from the user in the form of an image. I followed [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) step documentation and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/). The result I got was correct, I received input from the terminal if the 'POST' method was successful by returning status code 200.
But why is the media folder in the root directory not created? I've changed the settings.py with this code
[image: Status code when user send image]

```
cartoon/views.py    
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError, HttpResponse
from .forms import CartoonImageForm
import cv2
import numpy as np
from django.http import JsonResponse

def cartoon (request):
  return render(request, 'cartoon/cartoon.html')

def image (request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CartoonImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid ():
      form.save()
      return redirect('success')
  else:
    form = CartoonImageForm()
  return render(request, 'cartoon/cartoon.html', {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('successfully uploaded')
```

This urls.py

```
# cartoon/urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from .views import cartoon, image

app_name = 'cartoon'

urlpatterns = [
    path('cartoon/', cartoon, name='cartoon_page'),
    path('result/', image, name='cartoon_result')
]

## MEDIA
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

cartoon/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import CartoonImage

class CartoonImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartoonImage
        fields = ['image_upload']
```

directory root settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
# Media file
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'media'
    
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

cartoon/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CartoonImage (models.Model):
  image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

This is templates html templates/cartoon.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cartoon</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <!-- Style -->
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
    }

    main {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary-subtle navbar-expand-lg border border-black">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div
          class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center"
        >
          <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2xl pt-0"></i>
          <p class="fw-bold fs-4 pt-2">Tubes Citra Digital</p>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-flex align-items-start">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="icon-link icon-link-hover link-offset-2 link-offset-3-hover link-underline link-underline-opacity-0 link-underline-opacity-75-hover"
                style="--bs-icon-link-transform: translate3d(0, -0.125rem, 0)"
                href="{% url 'home:home_page' %}"
              >
                <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket bi" aria-hidden="true"
                  ><use xlink:href="#clipboard"></use
                ></i>
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <!-- From file-->
      <!-- {% url 'cartoon:cartoon_result' %} -->
      <form
        id="cartoon-form"
        action="{% url 'cartoon:cartoon_result' %}"
        method="post"
        class="validate container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center flex-column"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="fs-1 fw-bold text-center">Turning an image into a cartoon.</p>
        <div class="custom-file mb-3">
          <div>
            <label for="formFileLg" class="form-label border-primary"></label>
            <input
              class="form-control form-control-lg border-primary"
              id="formFileLg"
              type="file"
              name="file_cartoon"
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-auto"
          type="submit"
        >
          Convert
        </button>
      </form>

      <!-- Display Hasil cartoon -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="cartoon-result-container">
            <img
              id="cartoon-result"
              alt="Cartoon Result"
              src=""
            />
            {% if error_message %}
            <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="">
      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div
        class="text-center p-3"
        style="background-color: rgba(28, 27, 27, 0.05)"
      >
        © 2023 Copyright:
        <a
          class="text-body"
          href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIcSWuKMwOw"
          target="_blank"
          >Click this link.</a
        >
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Script CDN-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/adc08351c2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case, in addition to the correct code status, the developer tools also do not issue errors. Maybe you guys can help me in this case. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

**EDIT**
After debugging now I can get the photo inputted from the user, but an error like the traceback below comes out.
In this case i already run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/

Django Version: 4.2.8
Python Version: 3.9.18
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'count',
 'cartoon',
 'scanner']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)

The above exception (table cartoon_cartoonimage has no column named image_upload) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\RH-KULIAH\SEMESTER 3\Ganjil\PCD\tubes_pcd_web\cartoon\views.py", line 16, in image
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 542, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\katana\miniconda3\envs\pcd1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /result/
Exception Value: table cartoon_cartoonimage has no column named image_upload
```

Comment: Try this: (1) Pass the form in the context of your `cartoon` view. `render(request, 'cartoon/cartoon.html', { 'form': CartoonImageForm() })`.  (2) Render the form field. Replace your `<input>` tag with `{{ form.image_upload }}`

Comment: maybe you have to create folder on your own - before you start server.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if your `POST` could be correct then it should run `redirect()` and it should show status `301` or `302` (or other `30x`). So maybe `form.is_valid ()` gives `False`. You could use `print()` to debug it.

Comment: "_table cartoon_cartoonimage has no column named image_upload_" are you sure you've generated and applied your migrations?

Comment: Yes iam sure,The table in question "table cartoon_cartoonimage" exists but the coloumn image_upload does not exist. There are only id and image columns. Will it be problematic when I rename the column?

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer you have to generate and apply the migrations each time you change / update your models. The reason they are called "migrations" is because you're migrating your DB from old application state to new application state.